How to fill-up previous job experience in DS-160 form
I'm going to fill up my DS-160 form for a B1/B2 visa soon. In the work experience section how do I input my previous job in a company where I worked for more than eight years and held several different positions? Like Assistant Developer to Junior Developer to Senior Developer to Lead Developer through promotions. Should I list them separately or just make one entry with my last designation for the entire time with that company?

This is a visa application, not a job application, so your exact job title is not important. I'd just add one entry with "Developer" as your title.

Thanks, will do that.
